# Specified cast is not valid exception in FreshMvvm Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

I am using FreshMvvm, getting exception at the starting of application.

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is
>   not valid. : at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object.7(intptr,intptr,intptr) : [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED
>   EXCEPTION: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

```
public App()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   var mainPage = FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel<StudentListPageModel>(); //Here getting exception
   MainPage = new FreshNavigationContainer(mainPage);
}
```

StudentListPage.xaml

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="{Binding StudentName}"  Font="20"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding StudentClass}" Font="20"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding City}"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
</StackLayout>
```

StudentListPageModel.cs

```
public class StudentListPageModel : FreshBasePageModel
  {
        private Student _student;
        public StudentListPageModel()
        {
            _student = new Student();
        }

        public string StudentName
        {
            get { return _student.StudentName; }
            set
            {
                _student.StudentName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("StudentName");
            }
        }

        public string StudentClass
        {
            get { return _student.StudentClass; }
            set
            {

                _student.StudentClass = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("StudentClass");
            }
        }

        public string City
        {
            get { return _student.City; }
            set
            {
                _student.City = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("City");
            }
        }
  }
```

Student.cs

```
public class Student
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string StudentClass { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

StudentListPage.xaml.cs file is empty

```
public partial class StudentListPage : ContentView
{
    public StudentListPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anything special in `StudentListPage.xaml.cs`? What is the base class?

Comment: Base class is `FreshBasePageModel` comes from FreshMvvm package. Total file I have pasted here nothing special.

Comment: I meant the page, not the ViewModel. Also, just to make it clear, what is inside `Student`?

Comment: `StudentListPage` should be of type `Page` or one of its child, not `ContentView`

Comment: Feeling stupid how come I added ContentView, But you are hawk-eyed thanks @foxanna

Comment: No problem, @Arvindraja. Everyone misclicks sometimes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every page that is corresponding to `FreshBasePageModel` should be a child of `Xamarin.Forms.Page`, `Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage` as an example. You can create it with "Forms ContentPage" template in Visual Studio: [image]